# I got a problem with setting eventlistener to button JS

Tags: javascript, function, eval, addeventlistener

When I tried set eventlistener to my button(condition with "^") I got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error at HTMLButtonElement..
What to do I don't know.
Thank you in advance)

```js
op = ["button","#hello","^somefun()","<father"];
var el = document.createElement(op[0]);

 if(op[s][0] == "#"){ 
  el.id = op[s].substring(1,op[s].length);
  s++;
  console.log(s);
 }
 // set class of element
 if(op[s][0] == "."){
  el.className = op[s].substring(1,op[s].length);
  s++;
  console.log(s,el.style.className);  
 }
 //set text that will be in element
 if(op[s][0] == "_"){ 
  el.innerHTML = op[s].substring(1,op[s].length);
  s++
  console.log(s); 
 }
//there i got a error!
if(op[s][0] == "^"){
  s++;
  el.addEventListener("click",function () {
   eval(op[s]);
  });
  s++;
  console.log(s);
}
```

Comment: `<father` ? What is `s` also?

Comment: What is `<father` i think that `<` sign is your problem

Comment: `"message": "ReferenceError: s is not defined",`

Answer (score 0):

When you put the call to `eval`, you pass in the full string stored in the array (`"^somefun()"`). `^somefun()` is a syntax error. You need to slice the string to exclude the `^`.

Some other things that may need reworking:

- Don't use `==`, for javascript, use `===`, it prevents unexpected behavior.
- Don't use `eval`, most of the time, it is a security concern
- Don't access the characters of a string like an array.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in comments, the issue is with the "op" and this line:

```
op = ["button","#hello","^somefun()","<father"];
```

Changing it to:

```
op = ["button","#hello","^somefun()","<father>"];
```

Will fix the issue.

Comment: it isn't HTML tag it's another option of this element. I used it to make some parent element to current element.

Comment: Maybe providing the full file being run. In the above snippet examples "op" isn't defined as a variable, as well as "s" which is causing console errors.